New site logo doesn't appear on Sites overview
I noticed that our new shiny logo doesn't appear on the site overview.


It doesn't appear on mempool chat either. I suppose some services won't show the icon until restarted. Surely normal.

Are you still experiencing this? Assuming you're talking about the sites list on https://stackexchange.com/sites, I'm seeing the new logo there now.

Thanks, it's fixed now!

The favicon on Chat is still the old one, though

@Murch: Looks like the icon is updated in chat now as well. I blame caching.

The new logo is visible on the site overview now.

